# Test there is character after a digit in XSLT

Tags: xslt

There is a string. I want to check whether there is a character after the digit or not.

Input:

```
<root>
  <information id="fig-FigF.3A"/>
</root>
```

Output should be:

```
<root>
  <!--xxx-->
</root>
```

tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="root/information">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="substring-after(@id,'\d') = '\c'">
       <xsl:comment>xxx</xsl:comment>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>  
       <xsl:comment>yyy</xsl:comment>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But my tried code, not workes as I expected. How can I do this?

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: A great improvement on your previous attempt to raise this question. But note that "FigF.34" also has a character ('4') after a digit ('3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
<xsl:when test="matches(@id, '\d\D')">
```

This looks for a pattern of digit followed by a non-digit.